# Squeaking After Rotor/Pad Replacement?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-pad

Anyone know what could be causing the squeaking in this clip? I recently had my rotors and brake pads replaced. It appears to only be coming from the right rear wheel. It doesn’t go away even after driving long distances.

Clip: https://vimeo.com/517173855

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like one of the backing plates is rubbing against a rotor.

Comment: @paulster2 thanks! Is this something I can do myself? If so, is it an easy fix and how can it be done?

Comment: First, figure out which exact wheel is making the noise. The backing plate is on the back side of the rotor (towards the interior of the vehicle, so opposite side of the wheel as you're looking at it). You'd need to crawl under the vehicle and inspect the backing plate to see if/where it's bent or touching. The easiest way to do this is to put the vehicle up on a jack stand at the corner where the noise is coming from, then spin the tire. Noise should be self evident and fairly easy to find. When found, take a screwdriver and pry the dust shield away from the rotor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late update, but it was the dust plate. I took the right rear tire off and the dust plate was just barely scraping the rotor on the bottom. I bent it back into place and problem solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Paulster2 recommends you can also see if the brake pad hardware is scraping against the rotor.  These are the small metal retainers the pads slide on - one on top and one on the bottom in each caliper bracket.  I have on occasion not centered them properly and they rub against the rotor and it makes a high pitched scraping sound when driving.  Since you had a shop replace them for you I would take it back to the shop and have them adjust since this would require removing the tire, the brake caliper and the brake caliper bracket - unless you are comfortable performing this work yourself.